# Get N last rows from table with one stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want get N last rows from table with one stored procedure.

My stored procedure has some parameters like `@PageNumber` and `@RowCount` and etc.

I have 2 problems :

- I need to count the rows and results in my user interface because I want to limit my user when he is in last page and press next page.
- I want my user can press last page when he is in other page.

**Tip:** I don't want to execute my stored procedure twice to get the results and row count because it creates dynamic and need long time for execution.

For more description I most say that my sp is like :

```
Create Procedure TestSelectBill  
(  
    @PageNumber int = 1 ,  
    @RowCount int = 5  
)  
As  
Begin  
    Select   
        *  
    From billing.BillMaster As BM  
    Where  
    ( Bm.SubscribeId = '12345674' )  
    Order by SubscribeId  
    OFFSET @PageNumber * @RowCount ROWS  
    FETCH NEXT @RowCount ROWS ONLY;  
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is my solution:

```
Select
  COUNT() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RowNumber,
    * 
From billing.BillMaster As BM  
Where  
( Bm.SubscribeId = '12345674' )  
Order by SubscribeId  
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @RowCount ROWS  
FETCH NEXT @RowCount ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Row_Number()` in your query and order `SubscribeId` descending and `row[0]["RowNumber"]` is total count
like this:

```
Select
        *  ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SubscribeId DESC) as RowNumber
    From billing.BillMaster As BM  
    Where  
    ( Bm.SubscribeId = '12345674' )  
    Order by SubscribeId  
    OFFSET @PageNumber * @RowCount ROWS  
    FETCH NEXT @RowCount ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: It is not a good answer. For example If my query without paging has 100 rows and I want to see second page with 10 rows, I will have rows between 11 and 20, but I need the number 100 also for creating 10 posible paging.